# Where did docker dangling images go?

Tags: docker

Usually, when I built Docker images, I used to get dangling images, with which I debugged Dockerfile instructions in case of failing commands.

Dockerfile example:

```
FROM alpine                       # Step 1
RUN true                          # Step 2: successful command
RUN false                         # Step 3: failing command
RUN echo "Next instructions..."   # Next steps
```

I would get something like `Error while building at 'RUN false'...`

I would have a dangling image corresponding to the successful `Step 2` in the Dockerfile:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>                  <none>              5e2dfc857e73        1 min ago           261.6 MB
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         dangling image ID after last successful instruction
```

From this dangling image, I would debug the failing `Step 3` with something like:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash 5e2dfc857e73
root@c6b4f3bf1d5d:/# false                           # I would debug the failing command here
```

But currently, with `Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a` and `Buildkit`, dangling images do not appear in `docker images -a` or `docker image ls -a`, so where did they go?